# EmberJS 404 Error Handling

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I'm dealing with error handling with EmberJS. Now I can handle my errors like this:

```
App.MediaShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
...
 actions:
     error: ()->
         @transitionTo '404'
```

But it is just a temporary decision. What I want to do now, is to render the '404' template within that route, where I get 404 error. For example, if I go to

> /media/111111

route and i get an 404 error, I don't want to transition to the 404 page, I want to stay on the same page, but render the 404 template in it. I tried it this way:

```
actions:
    error: () ->
        @render '404',
            into: 'media.show'
```

but it is not working :) I will be grateful for your help :)

Comment: Edu, nope, this is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to look at the `ErrorRoute` and `error` template [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates).

It doesn't exactly handle error codes very well, but when you reject the `promise` from the `model` on your `App.MediaShowRoute` your error will become the content of the `ErrorController`... You can then check for it in your `ErrorRoute#renderTemplate`

```
App.ErrorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    'renderTemplate' : function() {
        switch (this.get('controller.content.code')) {
            case 404 : return this.render('404');
            default : return this.render();
        }
    }
});
```

Take a look at my blog post for a more in depth example of how you might pass the error code around:  http://www.riverrockapps.com/post/improving-error-route-in-emberjs

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is really helpful, but I forgot to say that I'm using Ember Data. So, can you help me with changes, that had to be made to my adapter.

Comment: You could also check the error controller content `controller.content` and compare against the reason string rather than using error codes, which would allow you to avoid modifying your adapter...  From the documentation: `The "reason" for the error (i.e. the exception thrown or the promise reject value) will be passed to that error state as its model.`

Comment: both links in the answer are no longer valid